# Communicating to MySql via PHP, on the iPhone developed with Adobe Air

Tags: iphone, ios, actionscript-3, air

I want to create an iPhone game with Adobe AIR, and I want that game to be able to store the players details in a MySql server.

1. What would be the best way to do that?
2. Is it possible to use a standard URLRequest in AS3, and have the iPhone use that to communicate to the PHP on the server, and receive back data?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach for this would be use a PHP front for the Mysql DB ( RESTful service ideally ). From your AIR app you can use HTTPService to communicate with the external PHP file.
[HTTPService](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/rpc/http/HTTPService.html) would perhaps use normal text or xml for communication. You can find further documentation about it in the link.